# Adding global models (e.g. wind)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am new to Gazebo and for my application I would need to add several dynamic models, the state of which influences the robot models present in the world.
A simple example could be a (time varying) wind model that needs to be accessed from within the robot models in order to compute aerodynamic forces.

From the gazebo documentation I was not able to work out what is the best way to implement something like the above.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/790/adding-global-models-(e.g.-wind).../) by [Renzo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/145/renzo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would create a WorldPlugin that contains the wind model. This model could either publish messages about the wind, or directly influence models.

Here is a tutorial about WorldPlugins:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/make_world/control

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Renzo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/145/renzo/) on 2013-01-14**:
Creating a WorldPlugin makes perfect sense. However I am not at all clear how I would get hold of the affected robot models in order to influence them directly (e.g. by applying a force). Could you point me to a place in the Gazebo code in which is shown how the world directly influences a model?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-01-14**:
You can try looking at the [SpringTestPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dbae83d18e023d9532ba7961b3a3653931e85d03/plugins/SpringTestPlugin.cc?at=default) and also the [Gazebo physics API](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/group__gazebo__physics.html).

**Comment by [Antares](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1203/antares/) on 2015-05-27**:
Could you please fixed that broken links?
I'm trying to do the same, but I cannot look into those links

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-05-27**:
[programmatic world control tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world_properties&cat=write_plugin), [physics api](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/group__gazebo__physics.html)